# AJAX submit form modals access

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Im beginner at JavaScript and AJAX I'm trying to put some security code before opening some modals.

I want to show different modals if clicked dataid = 1 or dataid - 2

```
href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-pincode" data-id="1"
href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-pincode" data-id="2"

<form id="idForm" method="POST">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label><?php echo $lang['pincode']; ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['pincode']; ?>" maxlength="5" name="pincode" id="pincode">    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" id="testButton" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $lang['send']; ?></button>
  </div>  
</form>
```

This is html code, this is the js part :

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
  var url = "/ajax.php?task=check-pincode"; // the script where you handle the form input.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data) {
      if ($.trim(data) === "ok") {
        $("#update-pincode").removeClass('fade').modal('hide');
        $("#edit-password").modal();                               
      } else {
        alert('Pin ERROR');
      }
    }
  });   
  e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

ajax.php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] == "check-pincode") {
  $pincode = (int) safe($_POST['pincode']);
  $id = (int) safe($_POST['id']);
  $checkpin = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE pincode='$pincode'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($checkpin) < 1){
    echo "error";
  } else {
    echo "ok";
  }
}
```

This I want to do here is if clicked dataid 1 to display #one-modal if clicked dataid 2 to display #second-modal and other modals but I cant get this data id value and in JavaScript check to display different modals.

And tell me how is this secured this ajax.php path ..
Any advice is welcome , sorry 4 my bad english

Comment: refer this link - https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-content-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/

Comment: i just need a simple if condition where (data === "ok" && here to get a data id and if 1 show onemodal else if (data === "ok" && data-id == 2) display other modal cuz i need for more modals to open any help?